# How to see default selection on select type without using an array

Tags: php, html

Im trying to set my website so when I enter an users form it selects their selection in the select box first and then the other answers below it. The select box only has two answers, Yes & No. But at the moment it is showing their answer up first in the $returned variable but then also listing the two answers below.

- currently see ;
  Yes
  No
  Yes

rather than their answer and then the other one.
The code im using is;

```
<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Returned:</label><select name="returned" style="width: 150px">
    <option><?php echo $returned;?></option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select></p></div>
```

How would I change the code to display the users answer in $returned and then the alternative answer below?

Thanks

Comment: By checking if $returned is the same as one of the other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a very user-friendly way to handle that as the order of the options changes with the answer.

Instead you should mark the selected one as selected.

A simple example:

```
<select name="returned" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="Yes" <?php echo $returned === 'Yes' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="No" <?php echo $returned === 'No' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ah not much point having 2 answers the same I will delete mine

Answer (score 2):

In PHP:

```
$returnedYes = ($returned == 'Yes') ? "selected=selected" : "";
$returnedNo = ($returned == 'No') ? "selected=selected" : "";
```

In HTML:

```
<option value="No" <?php echo $returnedNo;?>>No</option>
<option value="Yes" <?php echo $returnedYes;?>>Yes</option>
```